# Issue Filling Hole in Mesh

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm following an apple sculpting tutorial and at some point, I seem to have accidentally deleted a vertex along with the four adjacent faces. I filled this hole using the methods I've learned thus far (used <kbd>F</kbd> to fill between vertices and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to add one vertex in the middle)

The apple now looks fine in edit mode, but when I switch to object mode, the faces appear to be triangulated. Furthermore, when I apply a subdivision modifier as instructed in the lesson, an unsightly patch appears where I filled the hole. Merging vertices by distance had no effect. The normals are not reversed. I'm using version 2.91 if that information's relevant.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: It looks like you have duplicated faces in that area. Select your whole mesh in edit mode, then press M (merge) and select "by distance". However, depending on how close the verts are in your "stem section", it may try to merge them as well. If there is any doubt, hide those concerning areas (with verts that are very close together) before you perform the merge operation. Although, correcting just the problem section from your image should remove exactly 9 verts (you can see in the bottom right corner when you merge). If it only removes 9, then you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a hole like this, don't press F to fill, otherwise you'll have one unique face and then you'll need to use <kbd>J</kbd> (join) or <kbd>K</kbd> (knife) to recreate 4 different faces and they won't even be correct, you 'll need to pull the central vertex to get the right curve:

[image]

What you should do instead is selecting 3 vertices on each side:

[image]

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> *(Face) > Grid Fill* to fill, and tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view) if necessary:

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you so much! That was driving me crazy.